# Spring Boot, Keycloak and runtime authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, security, keycloak

Question about how to approach the solution for the following requirements.

- "user" role can have access to all actions in spring boot web api from 0:01am to 11.59am
- in other times user is not allowed to modify data (POST, PUT and GET requests).

Are there any way to customize Spring Boot Security or Keycloak adapter to have it execute authorization check in runtime instead of configure security only when application started.

Comment: Can't follow you, authorization check is always done at runtime. With Spring Boot Security you may follow this https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration. Have a look at `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String n)`, you may return a role depending of the actual system time.